# trying to call my function from a click event JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button; when I click the button I want my function to get a random image (using colors temporarily) I know the code in my function works, but when I try to call the function from the .click event the function doesn't seem to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function getRandomImage() {
  if ($("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black") == $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black")) {
    $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "red");
  }
}

$("#mainButton").click(function(){
getRandomImage();
});
```

I know I'm missing something/doing something off, please help :)

Comment: What does the console logs say? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try writing the click event inside document.ready()

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mainButton").click(function(){
            getRandomImage();
         });
    });
```

Ouside document.ready() you should write the function

```
 function getRandomImage() {
  if ($("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black") == $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black")) {
    $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "red");
  }
}
```

Else you can directly call the function from the button.

```
<input type="button" onClick="getRandomImage()" id="mainButton" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your jQuery code is wrapped in a document ready like so:

```
<script>
    function getRandomImage() {
      if ($("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black") == $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black")) {
        $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mainButton").click(function(){
            getRandomImage();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, since you didn't show the HTML, you need to make sure that the ID attribute is set:

```
<input type="button" id="mainButton" />
```

JQuery selectors (like your `#mainButton`) immediately search the document model to find the element to attach the event to. If you call the jQuery code before the document has loaded, it will likely not find the element because it doesn't exist yet. So you use the document ready to ensure the jQuery code runs after all the elements have loaded into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getRandomImage() {
    if ($("#imageContainer").css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
        $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "red");
      }
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mainButton").click(function(){
        getRandomImage();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all very much, I brain lapsed this worked best for me but again thank you all!

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mainButton").click(function(){
            getRandomImage();
         });
    });
Ouside document.ready() you should write the function

 function getRandomImage() {
  if ($("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black") == $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "black")) {
    $("#imageContainer").css("background-color", "red");
  }
}
Else you can directly call the function from the button.

<input type="button" onClick="getRandomImage()" id="mainButton" />
```